# Formulario que me diga cual es el valor del transporte con DJANGO. al seleccionar el colegio y el lugar donde vive me aparezca la tarifa (valor)

Tags: django, django-forms

[image: Aqui estan los models][image: Aca en el view traido los colegios y destino que tengo en el admin[![Aqui traigo los colegios que tengo agragados en el admin y los muestro en un menu desplegable]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sc3Pd.png)

Formulario que me diga cual es el valor del transporte con DJANGO. al seleccionar el colegio y el lugar donde vive me aparezca la tarifa (valor)

Comment: Sea más específico con su pregunta.

Comment: deberias agregar tus models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para esto debes usar algo de ajax, jquery similar a los combos dependientes.
Primero que nada te sugiero unos ligeros cambios en tus models:

```
    class Colegio(models.Model):
        nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.nombre
        ......
        ......

    class Destino(models.Model):
        nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.nombre
        ......
        ......
   class Tarifa(models.Model):
        colegio = models.ForeignKey(Colegio, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        destino = models.ForeignKey(Destino, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        precio = models.FloatField()
        def __str__(self):
            return self.precio
        ......
        ......
```

Como puedes notar en los modelos no es necesario definir el id, dado que por defecto Django ya lo hace por id y lo pone con el nombre de id  y autoincrementable, tambien otro cambio seria cambiar:

> nombre_colegio, nombre_destino

por :

> nombre
>   de esta forma es mas claro y asi estipula la mayoria de manuales y reglas basicas de diseño y analisis de base de datos.
>   en tu html:

```
    <select name="colegio" id="colegio" onchange="consultarPrecio();">
      <option value="" select disabled>Seleccione</option>
      {% for colegio in contratos %}
        <option value="{{ colegio.pk }}">{{ colegio.nombre }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <select name="destino" id="destino" onchange="consultarPrecio();">
      <option value="" select disabled>Seleccione</option>
      {% for destino in destinos %}
        <option value="{{ destino.pk }}">{{ destino.nombre }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
  <input type="text" name="tarifa" id="tarifa">
```

Si te fijas lo que se hace es agregar el evento onchange , y mediante javascript obtengo dichos valores y consulto en el model Tarifa, el codigo Javascript seria algo asi:

```
function consultarPrecio(){
 //obtengo los valores de mis select y valido que hayan sido seleccionados
  var colegio = $("#colegio").val();
  if(colegio == "" || colegio == null){
    alert("seleccione el colegio !!");
    return false;
  }
  var destino = $("#destino").val();
 if(destino == "" || destino == null){
    alert("seleccione el destino !!");
    return false;
  }
       //token
        var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "consultar_tarifa",
            data:{
                csrfmiddlewaretoken : csrftoken, 
                colegio:colegio,
                destino:destino
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                codigo = data.resultado;
                tarifa_data = data.precio[0];
                if(codigo=='ok_select'){
                   $("#tarifa").val(tarifa_data.precio);
                }
            },
            error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {

                if (jqXHR.status === 0) {

                    alert('Error al intentar Conectarse: Verifique su conexion a Internet.');

                } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {

                    alert('La Pagina solicitada no fue encontrada [404]');

                } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {

                    alert('Erro Interno [500]');

                } else if (textStatus === 'parsererror') {

                    alert('Error en el retorno de Datos. [parseJson]');

                } else if (textStatus === 'timeout') {

                    alert('Tiempo de Espera agotado');

                } else if (textStatus === 'abort') {
                    alert('Solicitud Abortada. [Ajax Request]');

                } else {
                    swal('Error desconocido: ' + jqXHR.responseText);

                }//end if 

            }//end error
        }); 

}//end function consultarPrecio
```

Tu urls.py:

```
 url(r'^consultar_tarifa', ConsultarTarifa, name='consultar_tarifa'),
```

en tu views.py:

```
def ConsultarTarifa(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':

        colegio = request.GET['colegio']
        destino = request.GET['destino']
        precio = Tarifa.objects.values().all().filter(colegio=colegio, destino=destino)
        precio_list = list(precio)

        data = {
            'resultado': 'ok_select',
            'precio': precio_list
        }
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
```

como se puede analizar lo que hago es obtener los valores de tus select(colegio, destino) mediante su id y luego se los envio x ajax hacia el views donde realizo una simple consulta y retorno la respuesta y esta la coloco en un input(tarifa) median el id.
Existe mas formas, espero te sirva y te pueda guiar.suerte !!

**Nota.-**
Cuando se hace llamados por ajax hacia django hay que incluir el token de django como estipula la documentacion ..revisala: [ajax django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/#acquiring-the-token-if-csrf-use-sessions-and-csrf-cookie-httponly-are-false)

Comment: Muchas Gracias. Mi pregunta es como añado la tarifa en el admin.

Comment: @tatianahernandez saludos en este caso debes registrar tu modelo en django admin..para ello debes modificar el archivo admin.py.. que es aqui donde se registra tu model.. para gestionar el mismo desde el panel admin

Comment: from django.contrib import admin
from miApp.models import Tarifa

admin.site.register(Tarifa)

Comment: con ello bastaria y podras visualizarlo desde tu admin de django y gestionarlo

Comment: te sugiero revisar : https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/es/django_admin/

Comment: si, ya lo tengo en el admin. Me refiero es como ingreso el valor porque se supone que es de tipo flotante

Comment: ingresas con (punto) algo asi: 1.25........ 1.250,89.............10.389,78..etc

Comment: Una pregunta si no que no m3 muestra la tarifa que le tengo que agregar

Comment: No me muestra la respectiva tarifa en el campo

Comment: te sugiero hacer un print precio_list ..en tu views para ver que retorna django hacia ajax..

Comment: Lo agrego y sigue sin aparecer

Comment: hay un return pero al igual no

Comment: tienes que ver por console que trae

Comment: o asu vez usa edita tu ajax...algo asi.. success: function(data) {console.log(data);.........}

Comment: con esto ves por el inspector de codigo->console a ver que retorna de django y como lo trae para posteriormente asignarlos o mostrarlos

Comment: mira que no funciona. Se supone que automaticamente deberia salir el valor

Comment: habra otra forma sin usar ajax

Comment: Me podria colaborar con un codigo que tengo pero no me sale la tarifa, no se que errores tenga. En con ajax @Tegito123

Comment: si claro@tatianahernandez comparte tu codigo o abre una nueva pregunta en stackoverflow

Comment: ya comparti el codigo en una nueva pregunta :) @Tegito123

Comment: @tatianahernandez saludos quiza ya solucionaste tu problema

Comment: jaja hice lo que dijiste de abrir una nueva pregunta y añadi la parte del ajax pero no funciona. @Tegito123